# Check if all elements in a list have a value in one of its properties - Can this be done in one line?

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, list

I have a method that accepts a list as a parameter what I want to do is check if ALL elements in the list have a string assigned to one of the properties - I know I can do this in a loop, but can I do this in one line ?

```
 MethodName(List<MyType> mytype)  
{
    if(mytype.name = "Test") << help here
    {
     //Do something
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548541(v=vs.100).aspx) like:

```
if(myType.All(r=> r.name == "Test"))
```

This will return `true`, if all the elements in the list has `name` property set to `Test` or if the list is empty.

Comment: .All - Cool! Never noticed that one. Thanks!

Comment: @user2537315, you are welcome, Remember `Enumerable.All` will return true for an empty list. If that is not the desired behaviour than you can add a condition `myType.Any()` to check if the list is not empty, So your condition could be `if(myType.Any() && myType.All(r=> r.name == "Test"))`